# JavaScript arguments, unexpected number error

Tags: javascript

When parsing the following argument the `console.log` states that the two numbers (arguments) are unexpected. Why is this and how could I fix this error?

```
function max(20, 20) {
 return width * height;
}
console.log(max(width, height));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the changes:

```
function max(width, height) //pass 20 to both width and height by calling function this way->> max(20,20);.
       {
       return width * height; 
       } 
       console.log(max(width, height));  
      //printing width and height
```

Now,why is `function max(20,20)` wrong?

- Whatever goes inside a function paranthesis(argument) should be a `variable declaration(or name of a predefined variable)`,it can not be a value.    You had entered `20,20` and `20` is not treated as a variable because variable names cannot begin with a number in javascript and almost all other languages.
- That is the reason you are getting an error.

Well,I know that you are confused because you have seen stuff like `max(20,20);`. Haven't you? This is called `calling the function and passing value to it`. I guess this is what you wanted to do.

- `max(20,20);` is a statement in which you are calling the function `max`. Here `(20,20)` is valid beacuse you can enter value as well because these values are supposed to be passed to `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be this way (your arguments cannot be direct values, it should be variables. And while calling them you should use values)

```
function max(width, height) {
 return width * height; 
}
console.log(max(20,20));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass values as arguments in definition of function, but when you'll call it, so your code should be like example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
//Definition
function max(width , height) {
  return width * height;
}

//Call
console.log(max(20, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function you tell the function the arguments you are going to use ,it is something like defining a variable to use it inside the function.You can't define number as arguments.Try to do it like this:

```
 function max(width , height) 
{
     return width * height;
}
console.log(max(20, 20));
```

and pass the numbers you want ,when you use the function ,not when you define it.